# oracle forms 10g not running on windows 8.1

Tags: forms, oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

In Oracle forms 10g when i click ctrl-R nothing happens the form is not displayed in my browser or anywhere although everything is correct and there's no errors. I am working on Windows 8.1 . So is anyone familiar with this issue ? how can i fix it ?

Comment: I think Forms 10 was only certified with Windows XP, so good luck :)

Comment: One tip, make sure you run "As Administrator" - maybe that'll help.